# Why are the "rules of combinational composition" useful?

Tags: digital-logic

I am reading Harris and Harris's *Digital Logic and Computer Architecture*. At the outset, let me define (precisely as they and, as far as I know, everyone else does) a combinational logic circuit (I emphasize that we are at the logic circuit level of abstraction) as a circuit whose outputs depend only on the current values of the inputs.

In the text, they give the **rules of combinational composition** (RCC) as:

> 1. Every circuit element is itself combinational.
> 2. Every node of the circuit is either designated as an input to the circuit
>    or connects to exactly one output terminal of a circuit element.
> 3. The circuit contains no cyclic paths: every path through the circuit visits each circuit node at most once.

They further remark that these rules give a sufficient but not necessary condition for a given circuit to be combinational, which is plainly true.

Now they give the following circuit as an example of a circuit which is *not* combinational, which seems very strange to me:

[image]

It is certainly true that this circuit violates requirement 2 of the RCC, but it still seems to me that this circuit is indeed combinational. Thus, I am led to the following two questions:

A) Am I correct that the circuit is combinational and that the authors should have said "the circuit does not obey the RCC but is nevertheless combinational"? **Edit: Now that I look at it, I see the trouble is that two gates are driving the same node and so we can potentially have some contention. I guess the point is that our output is not well-determined (i.e. not fixed) by the inputs in this case.**

B) If I am right about A) (**Per the edit above, I am not, but my question here still stands**) then I am immediately led to wonder why on Earth the RCC are useful if they are so undiscerning as to not "recognize" the circuit above (**or, rather, some other combinational circuit which does not obey RCC**) as combinational?

Comment: In short you have two outputs connected together.  While this is likely to behave in a repeatable if not predictable way in a real-world circuit, its behaviour is undefined at a theoretical level, so it’s not a valid circuit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question and the answer to this is sort of subjective but I will try my best.

There are two types of circuits in Digital Logic Design.

1. Combinational Circuits
2. Sequential Circuits

Now my first thought is if the author or someone say that the circuit, in discussion, is not a combinational circuit according to RCC, then my immediate question is what do we call it? (not sequential for sure)? So we see that the categories are limited, only binary choices here.

Now here is the catch, for a circuit to be categorized in either of two classes, it must be a valid logical circuit. How do we validate a circuit?, it is pretty simple. Analyze this circuit mathematically: the first thing is, **what is the equation of this logical circuit?**

No matter how hard you try, you will not be able to write a stable equation for this circuit. So this means that, theoretically, this is an invalid digital logic circuit/design. So before categorizing a circuit in either of two classes (combinational or sequential), it needs to be validated first. In the current case, the circuit is not a valid digital circuit so we can not take it to the categorization stage.

Definition of combinational composition would be more complete if someone adds another clause to RCC that there must be a valid mathematical equation of the digital logic (I think currently, it is just assumed).

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer. I appreciate you pointing out in particular the tacit criterion of a valid (well-defined) equation. I am going to wait a little bit to see if anyone else can comment on my question 2 a little more, but I think this gets me pretty much all the way there.

Comment: @EE18 I haven't ever encountered the term `combinational` before. Certainly, `combinatorial` vs `sequential`. But not combinational. That said, there is logic that used to be applied to PAL/GAL devices which were a specific category of combinatorial logic. [Here's an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8SHl.png) On left is something that could be programmed into a GAL. On right, not so. Both have the same k-maps. But the right minimizes by re-using an intermediate term. Is it possible that `combinational` is meant to mean logic as on the left, not the right, despite both having same k-maps?

Comment: This is not a criteria that if a logic cannot be implemented on GAL.PAL device so its not a combinational logic. Logic implementation is device specific and it has no right to alter the definition.

Comment: Secondly, about the combinatorial and combinational, they both mean the same thing. Combinatorial was used earlier but not combinational is used more oftenly. Somewhere in the past 35 years, without any fanfare, the language usage has drifted. Both terms are valid, but Combinatorial is the older term and Combinational is the newer term that is now in popular use. When or why this shift occurred is a topic for further research.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Combinational_logic

Comment: @ImGroot Then it is quite simple. Combinational is combinatorial. There's nothing difficult about that meaning. It's quite simple.

Comment: Yes. Combinational is combinatorial. But I have stated the reason anyway.

Comment: @ImGroot I don't think the three rules that EE18 stated are appropriate, then. I agree with #1 and #3. Not #2. As I am capable of reading them, anyway.

Comment: May I ask what you worry about with #2 @periblepsis ?

Comment: @ee18 You can ask. But I held short of writing anything here when considering writing to you when you first asked this for exactly this reason of saving my breath on *creating definitions* I'd need to explain myself. Worse, I'd be going out on a limb interpreting those words without having read the book you are using. And that is a huge and dumb mistake to make. I didn't have the time to correct that situation before writing.

Comment: That is very fair. At any rate, I would appreciate any insight on the topic from you as always :) @periblepsis